# Application not working after pushing to Heroku

Tags: python, git, heroku, bottle

I deployed my application to Heroku but it's not running !

This is the output of the "git push heroku master" command:

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> Using Python runtime (python-2.7.8)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.5.6)
       Cleaning up...
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web

-----> Compressing... done, 37.6MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://xxxxx.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:xxxxx.git
   46ff457..1712c4b  master -> master
```

Contents of my Procfile:

```
web: python main.py
```

My main.py:

```
import bottle
import os

@bottle.route("/request")
def tryquestion():
 return '''
    <form action="/request" method="post">
        Enter you request: <input name="request" type="text" size="65" />
        <input value="Search" type="submit" />
     </form>
    '''

@bottle.route("/request", method="POST")
def answerq():
    q = request.forms.get('request')

    ##### my code #####


bottle.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000)))
```

Log file:

```
2014-07-15T16:24:45.361567+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2014-07-15T16:24:45.361592+00:00 app[web.1]:     from umbc2 import sss
2014-07-15T16:24:45.361599+00:00 app[web.1]:     from requests import get
2014-07-15T16:24:45.361641+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named reques
ts
2014-07-15T16:24:46.801880+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-07-15T16:24:46.791054+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-07-15T19:32:07.105615+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=d9d90a2b-8367
-4b3d-94b8-aecf5c2700a8 fwd="99.231.120.219" dyno= connect= service= status=503
bytes=
2014-07-15T19:32:07.254940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=f3
0601cc-9703-494e-83ff-7ea3b95aea81 fwd="99.231.120.219" dyno= connect= service=
status=503 bytes=
2014-07-15T19:32:07.304050+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=cd
1ff90b-6644-4f79-b0fc-745f0480c3b7 fwd="99.231.120.219" dyno= connect= service=
status=503 bytes=
2014-07-15T19:32:26.459193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/result" host=xxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=93a8d94
9-8f1b-4f1b-ad00-a1cbf8167bef fwd="99.231.120.219" dyno= connect= service= statu
s=503 bytes=
```

After checking the logs, it gives an error on importing requests. I added requests to the requirements file and the application is up and running.

Thanks all for helping

Comment: Nothing in the output shows an obvious error.  But, a Procfile where you simply run an arbitrary script instead of start up a framework is fairly unusual.  Can you explain what `main.py` is supposed to do and why you think it's not working?

Comment: my main.py is working on my local, but when I deployed the application on heroku the website is not running.

Comment: What does "not running" mean? What happens when you browse to the site? HTTP 500? Have you looked in your logs?

Comment: When I browse the site "http://xxxx.herokuapp.com/request" I get Application error: An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details

Comment: Again, what exactly does main.py do and in what way does it work locally?  What do you expect to happen when you navigate to xxxx.herokuapp.com/request and why do you expect that to happen?

Comment: I added the code for main.py, when I run it locally "http://localhost:5000/request" I get a message "Enter your request" with a text box to submit. I expect xxxx.herokuapp.com/request to show the same result as main.py

Comment: Ah, it's bottle!  That's the relevant bit of information.  I'll add that to your question's tags.

Answer (score 0):

running bottle app for heroku you need these spec

first procfile add this

> web: python ./main.py $PORT

and Make sure you having requirement file add bottle there.

Comment: I changed the Procfile as you suggested and I already have bottle in my requirement file but nothing changed, I still get Application error when I run my applicaiton

Comment: After checking the logs, it gives an error on importing requests. I added requests to the requirements file and the application is up and running.

Thanks for the guidance